# Checking if instance of private static nested class

Tags: java

The title of the question sounds like a good thought experiment. Sadly it isn't. Lets assume the following code structure:

```
class Outer {
    private static class Inner implements SomeInterface {
        ...
    }
    public static SomeInterface returnInner() {
        return new Inner();
    }
}
```

Is there a good, clean way of performing the following check:

```
SomeInterface a  = A.returnInner();
if (a instanceof Outer.Inner)
    throw new Error("Ooops, something bad happened");
```

You think this isn't a real life example? Check the `Arrays` class and the method `asList(T ...)` which returns its own `List<T>` implementation, which just happens to be an `private static class ArrayList<T>` (which has nothing to do with the usual `ArrayList` - thanks Sun and Oracle what would I do without you). I need to check whether the object passed to my method isn't an instance of this wrapper class, because it does not implement the `add()` method (it uses the implementation of `AbstractList` - it throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`).

Comment: That's not something you can reasonably check. In any case, you'd have to worry about other lists that don't support `add`, like `Collections.unmodifiableList`, or Guava's `ImmutableList`, or who knows what else.

Comment: Is there really no good way of checking this? Even through some reflection magic?

Comment: Sure, there's nasty reflection stuff you could do, but it's not really *better* to do the nasty reflection stuff. You'll still get `UnsupportedOperationError`s when someone passes in a type that doesn't support `add`, and now you'll also have to deal with `SecurityException`s when a security manager stops you or `ClassNotFoundException`s when the class name changes.

Comment: ‘Static inner’ is a contradiction in terms. This is a static nested class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there really no good way of checking this? Even through some reflection magic?

There is a way, but it is not a good one by any measure:

```
// WARNINIG: This is very fragile, please try avoiding code like this.
if (theirList.getClass().getEnclosingClass() != null) {
    // theirList is an instance of an inner class
}
```

The problem is not that it is hard to do, but that the result becomes very unreliable:

- **This code rejects mutable implementations of `List<T>`** - for example, if you decide to roll your own nested class implementing `List<T>`, it would be rejected
- **This code would accept a top-level read-only implementation** - if Oracle decides one day to move the implementation to top level, your code will stop working.

For these reasons it would be better to try adding to the class, catch the exception, and take whatever alternative that you were going to take when the caller passes you a read-only list.

Answer (score 3):

It's a horrible, dirty, error-prone practice, but you can check the class' name. An inner's class name is the enclosing class' name followed by `$` and the inner class' name. In this case:

```
SomeInterface instance = Outer.returnInner();
if (instance.getClass().getName().equals(Outer.class.getName() + "$Inner")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Ooops, something bad happened");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers up to now generalize to a ***real*** `instanceof` implementation and merely check class equality. This doesn't handle the situation where `returnInner()` returns a *subclass* of `Inner`.

It's not too hard to emulate `instanceof` using reflection by recursively checking all superclasses and interfaces.

```
private static boolean isInstanceOf(Class<?> clazz, String type) {
    if (clazz.getName().equals(type)) {
        return true;
    }

    Class<?> superClazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    if (superClazz != null && isInstanceOf(superClazz, type)) {
        return true;
    }

    for (Class<?> interfaze : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
        if (isInstanceOf(interfaze, type)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (isInstanceOf(o.getClass(), "my.package.Outer$Inner")) // or
if (isInstanceOf(o.getClass(), Outer.class.getName() + "$Inner"))
```

*The same fragility warnings apply as with all reflection usage of non-public elements: The element(s) in question are not non-public without reason. The reason is that these elements can change without notice when a library updates or when your program is run with a different JRE version.*